# Cygwin and git ssh key

Tags: windows, git, ssh

We have **GitLab** server in out local network. I use **Windows 7**.

First I set up **GitBash**. I generated ssh key, saved it into GitLab account. Then I can do "clone, pull/push" requests to server (from GitLab and from cmd.exe).

Then I did same things for **cygwin** (generated key, saved it into account...). But cygwin can't connect to server. Cygwin freezes on every remote request. There are no errors or something useful. And that key work correct, when I connect to remote linux machines.

How to fix that problem?

Comment: Could you add more details please? What were the ***exact commands*** that you used to generate and add your ssh keys, both in msysgit Bash and Cygwin?

Comment: I used ssh-keygen command. Then I found id_rsa.pub in ~/.ssh folder, and saved it in my account. GitBash and Cygwin use different home and .ssh folders.